# Can a custom header be sent with a Cognito Form webhook?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a need to send a custom header with the webhooks from a form. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to send custom headers from [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) when posting JSON data to custom webhooks.  However, you can create a proxy handler that catches the hook from Cognito Forms and forwards the JSON on to the destination server with the additional custom headers.